# Navigation Timing API showing Internet explorer (9+) loading pages faster than Chrome

Tags: performance, internet-explorer, navigation-timing-api

I am using the [Navigation Timing API](http://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing/) to get real user performance data for visitors to my company's site. I am looking at visitors who use Chrome, Firefox, and IE 9+ and focusing on two main matrices of measurement:

**Page Load** => (loadEventEnd - navigationStart) and 
**Interactive** => (domInteractive - navigationStart)

I have gathered a lot of data and have noticed something unexpected, IE9+ has lower page load and interactive times than chrome and firefox. Has anyone else experienced this? Does IE set the navigation timing events differently than Chrome and/or Firefox? From all the performance sites I have looked at Chrome and Firefox should be much faster at loading pages than IE. I have looked over my code and tested dozens of time to ensure I am capturing data from the API correctly and appropriately storing it in my DB. Any thoughts?

Comment: Is the overall time loadEventEnd - navigationStart quicker for IE9 as well?

Comment: I have the same issue. Haven't found a solution yet.